# How to remove null selected values from a react-select multi select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have been trying to set up `react-select` but when I enable `isMulti` there is always two selected blank values in the selection box.

[image: Image of two blank values in the dialog box]

I have tried setting default values, using state to control the `Select` but it keeps showing these two blank values when I load the page. Here are some code snippets of the things I have tried:

```js
<Select
    isMulti
/>
```

```js
<Select
    isMulti
    defaultValue={[]}
/>
```

```js
<Select
    isMulti
    options={majors().map((element: any) => {
                return { value: element[2], label: element[2] }
             })}
/>
```

```js
<Select
    isMulti
    defaultValue={[]}
    options={majors().map((element: any) => {
                return { value: element[2], label: element[2] }
             })}
/>
```

```js
interface Option {
  value: String,
  label: String
}

let def : Option[] = []

<Select
    isMulti
    defaultValue={def}
    options={majors().map((element: any) => {
                return { value: element[2], label: element[2] }
             })}
/>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-leakey-coctqp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Hmkyriacou have you tried explicitly defining isMulti={true}?

Comment: @Vadym Yes, I have tried that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not entirely sure the reason for this, but what ended up fixing the problem was wrapping the `<Select>` inside of a `<div>`.

This did the trick:

```js
<div>
<Select
    isMulti
    defaultValue={[]}
    options={majors().map((element: any) => {
                return { value: element[2], label: element[2] }
             })}
/>
</div>
```